# Error: Could not find the main class

Tags: java, database, etl, talend

I'm using Talend to perform some ETL and I'm getting the following error when I try to run it.

```
Starting job bmcu_att_insert at 17:11 26/03/2012.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bmcu_att_summ/bmcu_att_insert_0_1/bmcu_att_insert
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bmcu_att_summ.bmcu_att_insert_0_1.bmcu_att_insert
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: bmcu_att_summ.bmcu_att_insert_0_1.bmcu_att_insert.  Program will exit.
Job bmcu_att_insert ended at 17:11 26/03/2012. [exit code=1]
```

Here is a screen shot of what I'm trying to run as well:

[image]

Comment: What is the Java command line? What is the classpath? Where is the class `bmcu_att_summ.bmcu_att_insert_0_1.bmcu_att_insert` defined?

Comment: bmcu_att_summ.bmcu_att_insert_0_1.bmcu_att_insert is the name of the project.. i'm not sure what the classpath is. I'm pretty new to all of this.

Comment: If you are pretty new maybe you should start with something simpler. Are you running this in Eclipse? It doesn't matter that it is the project, the start-up is complaining that the `class` of that name is not found. Have you defined a class with that name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to reinstall the program for it to work. How silly.

Comment: @precose All you have to do it remove the .Java folder from the workspace folder in your talend directory then reopen talend. This seemed to fix all of my problems. No need to reinstall

Answer (score 1):

This may sound silly, but give it a try anyway.

Create a new job within the same project and copy and paste all your components from that one into the new one (you can just do ctrl+a, ctrl+c and then paste into the new job, it'll keep everything).

Try running the new job instead.

Answer (score 0):

I Created a new Talend Workspace, added a new project to the workspace and imported all jobs/components to the new project in the new workspace and everything worked fine for me